# How to reroute rails to skip the #new action and go straight to #editing (that new entry)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, routes, crud

My notetaking app uses ajax to save changes to a note as a user types. It works really great when you are editing a note.

However, when I make a "New Note" every change is saved as a New note. No good. I end up with many notes when I should just have one.

So is there a way to reroute the user somehow... so that when you click on "New Note" a new note is created in the background... and then your just immediately Editing a blank note?

I realize I may be thinking about this all wrong. So suggestions are welcome for how to better solve this.

If you take a look at Evernote's web app - I am basically kind of just mimicking that functionality - although the design is a little different.

- -

Relevant CODE:

My notes controller.

```
class MicropostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :signed_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      flash[:success] = "Note created!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      @feed_items = []
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @micropost.update(micropost_params)
        format.html { redirect_to current_user, notice: 'Note was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @micropost }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @micropost.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def show
  end

  def index
  end

  def destroy
    @micropost.destroy
    if @micropost.destroy
      flash[:success] = "Note deleted!"
      redirect_to current_user
    else
      flash[:success] = "Oops! Something went wrong."
      render 'static_pages/home'
    end
  end

  private

    def micropost_params
      params.require(:micropost).permit(:content)
    end

    def correct_user
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to root_url if @micropost.nil?
    end
end
```

My "Form" -- I'm using content editable then grabbing that w/ JS and tossing it in the form.

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, remote: true, :html => {:id => "noteform"}) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new micropost..." %>
  </div>
  <%= button_tag( class: "useicons clear save-button the-logo", type: "submit", title: "save", onclick: "return getContent()") do %>
     <%= image_tag("upload.svg", alt: "Upload") %>
     <span class="verbal saveit clear">Save</span>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

JS to grab content editable and put it in a form field then use ajax to post it after 3 second pause.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function getContent(){
          document.getElementById("micropost_content").value = document.getElementById("haiku-note").innerHTML;
      } setInterval( "getContent()", 0 );
  </script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  function closeWarning(){
      return 'Unsaved changes. Give it a second. Then go.'
  }
  var timer;
  var timeout = 3000;
  $('#haiku-note').on("input", function() {
      clearTimeout(timer);
      window.onbeforeunload = closeWarning
      if ($('#haiku-note').val) {
          timer = setTimeout(function(){
              $('#noteform').trigger("submit.rails");
              window.onbeforeunload = false;
          }, timeout);
      }
  });
  </script>
```

And here's part of a sidebar where you can go to the Notes List page and the New Note page.

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button class="icoround dropdown-toggle sr-only the-logo" type="button" id="dLabel" data-toggle="dropdown">
          <span style="font-size:40px;">&#9776;</span>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "New Note", root_path %></li>
          <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Notes", current_user %></li>
          <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Account", edit_user_path(current_user) %></li>
          <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "About",   about_path %></li>
          <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
          <li role="presentation"><%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Let me know if you need to see more code, also, the full project is on [github](https://github.com/austinsamsel/haiku)

Comment: This could be a good use case for a JS MV* framework such as backbone. You could use it to handle use cases such as this as it will know if the model is persisted or not.

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Comment: i added the code - please let me know if you need to see anything else. thanks!

Comment: Conceptually this might work... I added `render js: "window.location.pathname = #{edit_micropost_path}"` under the #create action in the controller. so that once the post is first SAVED, then it redirects to the edit page for further edits. However, I'm having trouble getting this to redirect.

Comment: so this is the line that should work ` render js: "window.location.pathname = #{edit_micropost_path(@micropost.id)}" ` but its not redirecting. 

In the console, I get the response, "window.location.pathname = /note/221/edit" so the code is being read - just not executed... hm.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my controllers #create action. So that when the Note is saved, it automatically redirects to Edit that Note.

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    if @micropost.save
      render js: "window.location.pathname = #{edit_micropost_path(@micropost.id).to_json}"
    else
    end
  end
```